# Cannot find a node_module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a problem with [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) package. It has typings inside the package, so if I've understood it correctly, typeScript should handle it itself. But any time I am trying to import it, I see `(5,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'reselect'`.

Code is very simple:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/reselect/src/reselect.d.ts"/>

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Actions from '../../redux/actions';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { MapDispatchToPropsObject } from 'react-redux';

import { SearchCity } from './index';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  places: state.searchPlaces,
});

const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsObject = {
  search: Actions.searchPlaces.searchPlace,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchCity);
```

Here I've added reference manually, but it doesn't work anyway.
I use webpack with ts-loader.
Thanks!

Comment: Where is located your  file `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Paleo It is placed in the root of the project. This file is placed in `src/scripts/components/search-city/`

Comment: Is the file `reselect.d.ts` a descendant of the directory `search-city`?

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the same error and the `no-unused-variable` tslint rule was the cause, reselect works after removing it.

After some googling it seems that rule causes many various problems, so I recommend using `--noUnusedLocals` (or `"noUnusedLocals": true`) typescript directive instead. The only problem is if you use some unused vars intentionally somewhere, you have to replace `tslint:disable` with `// @ts-ignore` there. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Redux Toolkit, resolve the issue by importing createSelector as follows:

> import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

it should fix the problem, it did for me